# Allow only visual overflow of JavaFX node

Tags: java, css, javafx, layout

I got quite simple question but I can't find answer to my case.
My goal is to "allow" only visual overflow of node and prevent resize of parent node like this:

[image]

I want to allow visual overflow of child *(right)* but I want to prevent resize of parent and clip it as black rectangle *(left)*. 
I am aware of `setClip` method but this way I get situation *(#1)* where child is clipped visually.

**Is it possible in JavaFX to allow visual overflow?**

I need it becauase I can't deal with centering of node in `StackPane` when nested children overflow but would be good to avoid clipping them. I want to get first situation but now i get second one:
[image]

Is there other solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard behavior for JavaFX `Region`s:

> Every Region has its layout bounds, which are specified to be (0, 0, width, height). A Region might draw outside these bounds. The content area of a Region is the area which is occupied for the layout of its children. This area is, by default, the same as the layout bounds of the Region, but can be modified by either the properties of a border (either with BorderStrokes or BorderImages), and by padding. The padding can be negative, such that the content area of a Region might extend beyond the layout bounds of the Region, but does not affect the layout bounds.

Here's a short example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Pane pane = new Pane();
    pane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BLACK, null, null)));
    pane.setMaxSize(500, 300);

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100, Color.FIREBRICK);
    rect.setOnMousePressed(this::handleMousePressed);
    rect.setOnMouseDragged(this::handleMouseDragged);
    pane.getChildren().add(rect);

    StackPane root = new StackPane(pane);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  private Point2D origin;

  private void handleMousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
    origin = new Point2D(event.getX(), event.getY());
    event.consume();
  }

  private void handleMouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
    Rectangle rect = (Rectangle) event.getSource();
    rect.setTranslateX(rect.getTranslateX() + event.getX() - origin.getX());
    rect.setTranslateY(rect.getTranslateY() + event.getY() - origin.getY());
    event.consume();
  }

}
```

This has a `Rectangle` whose parent is a `Pane` but allows you to drag the `Rectangle` anywhere, even outside the bounds of the `Pane`.

Comment: Your code did not work in my project at the beginning but as it was correct standalone so I found that my problem was caused by putting content into Group and becuase of this whole layout acted differently.

Answer (score 3):

If you set the absulute position and size of the children yourself, you can make the parent layout ignore a child by setting [the `managed` property](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#managedProperty) to `false`. Unmanaged nodes are not repositioned/resized by the parent and are ignored when calculating the layout bounds of the parent.

```
child.setManaged(false);
```

Comment: Do I need to do any additonal things? I tried this and in general I see that not managed node don't grow and somehow It works but not for my case. For some reason "grandchild overflow" and pierces to Stackpane above and still moves. Is that problem related to fact i used Group somewhere between? My structure is StackPane > Group > Pane > Image + overflowing content. I tried to set managed to false for Pane and or children or even to all of them and somehow Stackpane still "see it" (but Pane for example don't grow anymore).

Comment: Nevermind, It's my fault because i put everything in scrollpane with group - this cause recalculation to visual content.